# How to manipulate a running software with python?

Tags: python

How can i manipulate a software while it running using python?

e.g:

I open a notepad on Windows 7 without write any word on it

[image: notepad before]

then i make program in python that he receive a string and when the user click on send button it write the String into notepad.

[image: software python]

if i write "abc" into python software and click on send button this should be the result:

[image]

Is it possible make a python script to manipulate the memory and add this string to notepad?

Comment: Please make an attempt at solving this on your own. If you have difficulty in one particular area come back with a more specific question.

Comment: @anmol_uppal That edits the file directly, rather than controlling Notepad.

Comment: @anmol_uppal i need to know if it's possible without manipulate a txt file.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the windows scripting host to send keys. Works on Python 2.7

```
import win32com.client
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run("notepad")
shell.AppActivate("Notepad")
shell.SendKeys("a") 
shell.SendKeys("b")
shell.SendKeys("c")
win32api.Sleep(500)
shell.SendKeys("d")
```

You can fine more on [this blog](http://win32com.goermezer.de/content/view/136/254/).

Comment: it works only for windows, right? but if it were linux or mac os? (i know there is no notepad there but have another text editor).

Comment: http://tjjr.fi/sw/python-uinput/ is a small, nice library which does it for linux. I am not aware of a single way to please all OS.

Comment: i'll look on it. You think it is possible write directly on memory of the running process?

Comment: Hard to say. Accessing memory heaps (especially writing) of other processes is not an easy pie. Sorry.